# Is there forward declaration of function in shell script -bash

Tags: c, bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forward declarations in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588457/forward-declarations-in-bash)

I have lot many functions in a shell script source file in which one calls other so Always I have to place the functions in the correct order.

Isn't there any thing like forward declaration of function in shell script as we have in C/C++ ?

**EDIT** : Or, is there any way to implement it ?

Comment: AFAIK, forward declarations aren't necessary at all. As long as you don't use a function before all its dependencies have been read by the shell.

Comment: @Mat : if not then suppose i am calling one function from other and definition of that function below it then it throws an error