# How do I create a function prototype in powershell?

Tags: powershell, function-prototypes

I can't find an example. How do I make a prototype for my powershell functions?

`function exampleFunc();
//other stuff that calls the example function
Function exampleFunc(){//stuff}`

Comment: There are examples on the [SO Docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/powershell/1673/powershell-functions#t=201607281323139314936)

Comment: I mean like 
`function exampleFunc();`
`other stuff that calls the example function`
`Function exampleFunc(){//stuff}`

Comment: You can't do that. Powershell isn't a compiled language.

Answer (score 6):

PowerShell doesn't support prototype functions, forward declarations or whichever term you want to use for this.  In PowerShell, when you use the `function` keyword you're defining a function.  If you call it twice with the same function name, you change the function's definition.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588457/forward-declarations-in-bash) about the same issue with bash lists the common methods to get around the issue.  You can do the same things in PowerShell.

Another option is to use the `Begin {} Process {} End {}` advanced function construct, and put all your function declarations in the `Begin {}` portion.

Answer (score 0):

You could call for snippets from Powershell ISE (Integrated Scription Environment) by right click or access via quick buttons Ctrl+J.

Answer (score 0):

And here is what @bacon-bits code would look like

```
function main()
{
    cls
    Begin
    Process
    End
}

function  Begin {

}

function  Process {

}

function  End {

}

main
```

Comment: prototyping a function would be a very useful feature to powershell.  I don't like to think about ordering by functions for usage.